# Will my HP officejet 6600 print and scan on Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, software-recommendation, printing

I am on XP ready to try Ubuntu. Will my HP 6600 print, scan and work wirelessly?

How about programs like Dragon Simply Speaking, AutoCAD and Garmim Map Updates?

Answer (score 0):

Yes but it looks like only from command line (No GUI), unless there is another Program out there that can. But those programs you mention should have access to the printer.

http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/officejet/officejet_6600.html